# $http response returns the entire index.html

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, angularjs-http

I have **site.com**. 
Each request is redirected here (so 'site.com/book', 'site.com/settings' ecc.. point to 'site.com')
Then I have **site.com/api/** where 'site.com/api/user', 'site.com/api/library/' ecc... are redirected.

I'm trying to use $http of AngularJS to request a JSON object to **site.com/api**.
On success, I receive status 200 but the response is the text/html of 'site.com/index.html'.

The headers sent with the request are: 
   Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*"
   Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8

I tried to debug **site.com/api/** with the app postman and it works as expected since I receive the correct JSON object.

I don't know if it is a problem of some .htaccess rule or the $routeProvider of AngularJS...
(I have a .htaccess file in 'site.com' and another one in 'site.com/api').
But I could be completely off the road. Maybe someone can help? Thanks.

```
var config = {method: 'POST', url: 'site.com/api/', data: $scope.data};
$scope.login = function(){
    $http(config)
    .success(function(resp, status, headers, config){
        console.log(resp);
    })
    .error(function(resp, status, headers, config){
        console.log(status);
    });
};
```

Comment: Please post the angular part of the code (or, alternatively, remove the angular tag)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried again with a clearer mind this morning.
It seems that I was missing the **http** part of the url **site.com/api/**.

So it can work both with

```
var config = {method: 'POST', url: 'http://example.com/api/', data: $scope.data};
```

or

```
var config = {method: 'POST', url: '/api/', data: $scope.data};
```